# Не доходит запрос до хаба. WebSocket ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, angular, websocket, signalr

Суть проблемы - запрос с клиента не доходит до WebSocket хаба.

Метод отправки запроса:

```
async SendPublicRSAKey(rsaKey: SendRSAPublicKeyDTO) {
    await this.HubConnection.send("SendRSAKeys", rsaKey);
}
```

Билдер подключения:

```
this.HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
        .withUrl("http://localhost:5172/schatHub", {
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
        })
```

Метод на стороне сервера:

```
public async Task SendRSAKeys(RSAKeyDTO rsaKey)
    {
        TradeKeys insertedKey = mapper.Map<TradeKeys>(rsaKey);
        insertedKey.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        insertedKey.nDataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(rsaKey.nData);
        insertedKey.eDataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(rsaKey.eData);
        await tradeKeyService.AddNewRSAKey(insertedKey);
        return;
    }
```

Конфигурация SignalR дополнительно не настраивалась, лишь

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
```

Никаких ошибок нет ни в браузере, ни на сервере.

При тестировании заметил, когда я отправляю весь объем данных, запрос не доходит.
Когда же я отправляю 1-2 свойства из всего объекта, 500 байт +-, запрос доходит.
Я игрался с конфигурацией, пытался настроить StreamBufferCapacity, MaximumReceiveMessageSize и т.д, но это не дало результата.

Comment: код нужно вставлять как текст, а не скрины

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Готово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что DTO классы на стороне клиента и сервера различались.

На стороне клиента у меня был объект с такими свойствами:

```
s: number[]
n: number[]
```

На стороне сервера:

```
public s: string { get; set; }
public n: string { get; set; }
```

Сопоставив отправляемый обект с сервером, запрос дошел до сервера.

Answer (score 0):

В SignalR,  поверх WebSockets есть ограничения на передачу данных в одном объекте,   как от сервера клиенту, так и от клиента к серверу.  И рекомендуемый размер это 32 kb.  Если будет заметно больше, то сообщения просто могут не передаваться.

Comment: Я использую: hubOptions.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 2000000; Это не решает проблему.